# GitHub API (Octokat.js): Cannot get Projects

Tags: javascript, github, github-api, octokit, octokat.js

I'm trying to access projects of a repository through GitHub API using [Octokat.js](https://github.com/philschatz/octokat.js/).

The API guide says I need to use preview header, which I am using:
https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/

I'm getting error for property `fetchAll` of `undefined` (= projects).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here - does anybody have an experience with this?

```
var Octokat = require('octokat')
var octo = new Octokat({
  // put your own token here
  token: 'XXX',
  acceptHeader: 'application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json'
})

octo.repos('YYY', 'ZZZ').projects.fetchAll((e, val) => {
  this.projectsList = val
})
```

Comment: It looks like Octokat.js didn't implement it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, turns out the API preview isn't implemented in the library yet.

https://github.com/philschatz/octokat.js/issues/144